# One Letter mistake allowed in exact word search

Tags: mysql, sql

we are implementing a search application

we have implemented a exact word search by the following sql query

```
SELECT *
FROM jreviews_content
WHERE jr_produits REGEXP '[[:<:]]ryan[[:>:]]'
```

which works well now we have another requirement in some of our field ie in jr_title field if the user fill one missing letter or one letter mistake or one extra letter for example if the user type restauran or restaunts or restaurants then it should give the result but not more than one letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow one alphanumerich character before the search string, and one after:

```
SELECT *
FROM jreviews_content
WHERE jr_produits REGEXP '[[:<:]][[:alnum:]]{0,1}ryan[[:alnum:]]{0,1}[[:>:]]'
```

if you want to allow one alphanumeric character before the search string OR one after, you could use this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM jreviews_content
WHERE
  jr_produits REGEXP '[[:<:]][[:alnum:]]{0,1}ryan[[:>:]]'
  OR jr_produits REGEXP '[[:<:]]ryan[[:alnum:]]{0,1}[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: will it serach for ryan also

Comment: @Ryandecosta first query will match ryan, sryan, ryans and sryans but for example not ryanss, second query will match ryan, sryan, ryans but not sryans

Answer (score 2):

Look for "Levenshtein distance"

An implementation is here

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

or as a compiled function

http://samjlevy.com/2011/03/mysql-levenshtein-and-damerau-levenshtein-udfs/

Answer (score 1):

Although not strictly answering yor question, [`SOUNDS LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like)  could be your best option:

```
SELECT *
FROM jreviews_content
WHERE jr_produits SOUNDS LIKE 'ryan'
```

This uses the [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm to compare strings.

Comment: though it doesn't fulfill my requirement but it is a good concept never heard of it

Comment: a question though my site is in french is sounds like accent insensitive i.e does it differentiate between è e

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex): *All international alphabetic characters outside the A-Z range are treated as vowels*, and in soundex the first letter is not encoded (it is used as-is) and all following vowels are ignored. So, accented vowels are catered for, but the C cédille "ç" would be treated as a vowel (ie ignored) in positions other than the first letter.

Comment: Though a brave effort, SOUNDS LIKE is, ultimately, an inadequate algorithm - because there is such little correlation between the way English words are written and pronounced. Now, the same idea in Hiragana/Katakana could work really well!

Answer (score 1):

check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

This is fundamental for any search engine.